# How to use a Frame in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

In WPF XAML I can use a Frame like this:

```
<Frame Source="Frame.xaml" />
```

In WinRT/Windows Style Apps I don't have the possibility to set a Source for the Frame. How can I use a Frame in WinRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the boilerplate navigation code you get from the Blank app template.  A frame is created in code at [App.OnLaunched](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched.aspx), and instead of the Source property, you'd use the [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242694.aspx) method.